Inconsistent CORS errors in React UI calls to ASP.NET Core 6 Web API
A React app is calling my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API. Things have been working fine for months with no CORS problems.
Starting this week, I started seeing the React client unable to call the API consistently.
Things work fine other environments. But in a STG environment requests are blocked, but inconsistently. That is, some requests to a single controller get through while others do not. In addition, reloading the UI page results in a different set of endpoint calls that fail.
I have not been able to identify the cause. I don't know if there is a change in React client code that could account for this. I haven't found anything unusual about the server where the API is hosted in IIS. I am not aware of any new security in that environment. Any suggestions as to what could explain the inconsistent CORS errors?
I believe I have CORS access correctly enabled in the API (this has worked for 8 months in all environments with no CORS issues):
private readonly string _policyName = "CorsPolicy";

services.AddCors(opts => {
            opts.AddPolicy(_policyName, builder => {
                builder.AllowAnyOrigin().
                        AllowAnyMethod().
                        AllowAnyHeader();
            });
        });

app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors(_policyName);

The fact that some requests get through seems to indicate CORS is configured appropriately in the API app.
The inconsistency must be a clue as to what is going on and how to resolve it.
From the Chrome browser dev tools Console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://some-domain.com/MyApp/SomeController/SomeEndpoint' from origin 'https://webapp-client.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
 
GET https://some-domain.com/MyApp/SomeController/SomeEndpoint net::ERR_FAILED 500 (Internal Server Error)

On calls that fail, the OPTIONS call returns:

500 Internal Server Error

On calls that succeed, the OPTIONS call returns as expected:
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:  authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:   *

Calling the same endpoint 20 seconds later, it may succeed, or it may fail.  It is inconsistent.
Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?
I have tried adding [EnableCors("CorsPolicy")] decorations to endpoint Action methods. No effect.
I have tried to identify why calls to some endpoints succeed while others fail. They are all implemented the same way.
I have asked the UI dev if there was a change from his end. No change he is aware of.
I asked the architect guy if there is a new security aspent in the affected environment. None he is aware of.
I have done many google searches similar to "Inconsistent CORS errors" but have not found anything that looks like my situation.
I would expect that a React client calls to an API endpoint would consistently fail or consistently succeed, all other things being unchanged.  In the past, CORS errors I have seen are consistent and can usually be addressed by an appropriate change.  At this point, I suspect a network security issue, but I have no way to verify that.
Any suggestions are appreciated.

I wouldn't call builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader() a "correct" policy, you're basically disabling CORS protection with that policy (just like setting a firewall rule to "allow all incoming"). A "correct" policy would allow only a minimal set of Origins and Methods.

Thanks for the feedback.  I agree with you.  In the current situation, however, I first need to resolve the blocking issue.  Then I can tighten up access to only what is needed.

The HTTP 500 on OPTIONS needs fixing first. (A common cause is having IIS's WebDAV defaults set on your Website, which means WebDAV handles OPTIONS requests before ASP.NET Core can).

Thanks for the feedback.  Things work fine in other environments without special configuration of WebDav.  Do you have any suggestion on what specific WebDav configuration to look at that could account for the issues I'm seeing?

We don't know if it's WebDAV or not though - you need to investigate that first by looking at the raw IIS logs.

The issue is no longer occurring.  I do not know what changed to create the problem or to resolve it.  I didn't make any changes.  Thanks for the feedback & suggestions.
